# Not showing Date value for input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two input date fields. I need a second input date field value based on the first input date field selection.

**HTML:-**

```
<label>First input date </label>
<input type="date" name="job_date" id="job_date"  style="width:100%;" required>

<label>Second input date </label>
<input type="date" name="due_date" id="due_date" style="width:100%;" required>
```

**Script:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#job_date').change(function(){
    
    var pazdate = $('#job_date').val();
    
    $.ajax({
     url: 'ajax1.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: {pazdate: $('#job_date').val()},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#due_date').val(data);

    }
    
 });
 
});

</script>
```

**PHP Form**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pazdate']))
{
    $currentDateTime = $_POST['pazdate'];
    $nextdue_date = strtotime("+12hours", strtotime($currentDateTime));
    $due_date = date("m/d/Y", $nextdue_date);
    echo $due_date;
    
}

?>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say `"Date value not working for Input Date Field"` - can you clarify what you mean please? Does the AJAX function retrieve a value OK? Are there errors? Does the `due_date` not display the returned value?

Comment: `<input type="date" />` -> _"`value`: A DOMString representing a date in **YYYY-MM-DD format**, or empty"_

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Not showing Date value for input field. Ajax function is okay. it seems ajax function is working. but due_date value not returned for second input date field.

Comment: @hyperort use ``console.log(data)`` and check what value you are getting from the server?

Comment: @NotABot yeah i got the following error in console:- does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: Then, as already suggested multiple times, adjust the format of the response into the mentioned format.

Comment: @Andreas I did already adjust the format. it won't work

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas said, you get value from your form as **YYYY-MM-DD format**, but return from ajax1.php **m/d/Y format**. It will not work. Code is OK, just change date format in PHP file and nothing more.

Comment: so can i change the format for Y/m/d i am right?

Comment: You can return right format from ajax, and "due_date" wil catch it without problem. $due_date = date("Y-m-d", $nextdue_date);

Comment: Hi Elika thx for your response. i can change now as per your instruction. issue still persists and the other thing is value returned by text box successfully but when comes to the Date field it wont work